# Python - Tkinter - i want get() value from Entry to use in function

Tags: python, tkinter, get, var, tkinter-entry

I can not retrieve a variable from "Entry" and then enter the variable to a function. For example, I want to retrieve "NbF" which is a variable "entry". I did in "set" and I can retrieve it with "get" but when I get a new text "entry" I do not get the new value.

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog, tkMessageBox

application = Tk()
application.title("Application Drone - Analyse Vidéo")


def getFile(): 
        varName = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename().encode('utf-8')
        Name.set('Path : ' + varName)

def convert(nbFrame):
    print 'ffmpeg -i pathVideo -r '+nbFrame+' -f image2 "temp%4d.png"' 

def detect():
    pass

def analyse():
    pass

frame1 = Frame(application, bg="blue",   width=560, height=100)
frame1.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)

frame2 = Frame(application, bg="red",   width=560, height=100)
frame2.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)

frame3 = Frame(application, bg="green",   width=560, height=100)
frame3.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)

frame4 = Frame(application, bg="yellow",   width=560, height=100)
frame4.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)

frame5 = Frame(application, bg="grey",    width=560, height=100)
frame5.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

#frame 1
Name=StringVar()
lab1 = Label(frame1, text="Step 1 : Recup video").grid(row=0,column=0)
butt1 = Button(frame1,text="browse",command=getFile).grid(row=0,column=1)
nameVideo = Label(frame1, textvariable=Name).grid(row=1,column=0)

#frame 2
NbF = StringVar()
NbPictures=StringVar()
lab2 = Label(frame2, text="Step 2 : Convert video to images").grid(row=0,column=0)
ent2 = Entry(frame2, textvariable=NbF).grid(row=0,column=1)
# ent2.pack()
NbF.set('nb frame')
recup2 = NbF.get()
butt2 = Button(frame2,text="convert",command=lambda :convert(recup2)).grid(row=0,column=2)
nbP = Label(frame2, textvariable=NbPictures).grid(row=1,column=0)

#frame 3
NbS=StringVar()
lab3 = Label(frame3, text="Step 3 : Detect shape").grid(row=0,column=0)
butt3 = Button(frame3,text="detect",command=lambda :detect).grid(row=0,column=1)
numberShape = Label(frame3, textvariable=NbS).grid(row=1,column=0)

#frame 4
NbC=StringVar()
lab4 = Label(frame4, text="Step 4 : Analyse QrCode").grid(row=0,column=0)
butt4 = Button(frame4,text="analyse",command=lambda :analyse).grid(row=0,column=1)
numberCoord = Label(frame4, textvariable=NbC).grid(row=1,column=0)

#frame 5
lab5 = Label(frame5, text="Step 5 : Send coordonates").grid(row=0,column=0)
butt5 = Button(frame5,text="send",command=lambda :send).grid(row=0,column=1)

application.mainloop()
```

Comment: i'm having a hard time understanding what the problem is here.  there are a few things that could be causing problems though -- the `.grid` method always returns `None`.  In your code you're assigning `None` to a lot of variables when I doubt you expect to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you meant:

```
butt2 = Button(frame2,text="convert",command=lambda :convert(NbF.get())).grid(row=0,column=2)
```

This defers calling `NbF.get()` until the button is actually pressed.  As the code was before, you were calling `NbF.get()` before the button was created and then passing that value to the function whenever you pressed the button.

---

As a side note, `butt2` in the above code will always be `None` which is almost certainly not what you wanted it to be.  The reason for this is because `Widget.grid` always returns `None`.  I would advise you to not create a widget and pack/grid it on the same line -- always split that into 2 lines:

```
butt2 = Button(frame2,text="convert",command=lambda :convert(NbF.get()))
butt2.grid(row=0,column=2)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. it works perfectly. I'll change all my **Widget.grid**.